# ionic time show in indian current time and add hour in current time

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

[image]Please give me suggestions on the code. Thank you
I get the error in the iondate picker.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat=" DD,  h:mm A" [min]="minDate"  [max]="maxDate"  [(ngModel)]="selectedDateString"  (ionChange)="pickerdata($event)" minuteValues="0,15,30,45, 59" ></ion-datetime>

 minDate:string = new Date().toISOString();
  maxDate:string =new Date().toISOString();

 let date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate());
      
        this.selectedDateString = date.toISOString();
       this.minDate = date.toISOString();
     
      // //setting maxdate
      date = new Date();
      date.setHours(date.getHours() + 24);
      this.maxDate = date.toISOString();
```

I want to add 24 hour to current time and bind to max value.

ionic time show in indian current time and add hour in current time

Comment: Please add more details such as the error you are facing, the format of the date time you are looking for, etc to your question.

Comment: i  added more detail please help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not creating a new `date` instance while assigning to the `maxDate`.

change your code to:

```js
const currentDate = new Date();

this.minDate = currentDate.toISOString();
this.maxDate = new Date(currentDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours() + 24)).toISOString();
```

Comment: Sorry sir your code in not showing today datetime. Is showing tomorrow time I upload new image please look

Comment: Today's date is 22nd June. It is showing correctly right?

Comment: When try to console.log the dates, you will know the exact minDate and maxDate.

Comment: you can see image in not showing time . and min date in  current time not showing.And I want to time show in indian timezone